# How do I write the following code as a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly,
     Is there a way for me to put variable declarations in a for loop?

E.g. the following:

```
var origh1 = $('#candidates img:eq(0)').height();  
var origh2 = $('#candidates img:eq(1)').height();
var origh3 = $('#candidates img:eq(2)').height();
var origh4 = $('#candidates img:eq(3)').height();
var thumb1h = $('#candidates img:eq(0)').height()*0.20; 
var thumb2h = $('#candidates img:eq(1)').height()*0.20;
var thumb3h = $('#candidates img:eq(2)').height()*0.20;
var thumb4h = $('#candidates img:eq(3)').height()*0.20;
```

Then using that those variables, I would like the following in a for loop. Naturally, 'origh1' should equal img:eq(i), where i = 0. So I imagine if origh1 were in the loop, it would be something like origh(i+1).

```
$('#candidates img:eq(0)').fadeIn('normal').delay(300).animate({ height : origh1}, 1200, 'easeInQuad');
$('#candidates img:eq(1)').fadeIn('normal').delay(300).animate({ height : origh2}, 1200, 'easeInQuad');
$('#candidates img:eq(2)').fadeIn('normal').delay(300).animate({ height : origh3}, 1200, 'easeInQuad');
$('#candidates img:eq(3)').fadeIn('normal').delay(300).animate({ height : origh4}, 1200, 'easeInQuad');
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each will do the job:

```
$('#candidates img').each( function() {
 var origh = $(this).height();
 $(this).fadeIn('normal').delay(300).animate({ height : origh}, 1200, 'easeInQuad'); 
});
```

To iterate over first 4 change it to:

```
  $('#candidates img:lt(5)').each( function() {
     var origh = $(this).height();
     $(this).fadeIn('normal').delay(300).animate({ height : origh}, 1200, 'easeInQuad'); 
    });
```

Comment: Hrmm....the problem with this is that it doesn't seem to iterate through img:eq(0) to say img:eq(14). And subsequent origh1 - origh15.

If I wanted to access origh5, how would I do that...based on this suggestion?

Comment: Correct, sorry, just copy-pasted this without additional thought.

Comment: You can use :lt or :gt to define the range of your images.

Comment: Can you update the code to reflect the use of :lt or :gt ? I understand the construct of what I want to do, it's just the syntax that bugs me out. 

Edit: I saw that you just changed it right after I submitted the comment. How do I access origh15 for example...based on that code. I see no allowance for incrementing origh, or am I missing something?

Also, do you have documentation of :lt and :gt ? Where I can read up about what it does and how to use it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not enough that you understand what you want to do, you need us to understand this either.

Comment: Huh? Sorry, don't fully understand your last comment.

Comment: I was saying you need to elaborate more, since to help you it's not enough to know what you understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Oh...sorry about that. LOL @ the link to the let me google that for you. I actually Google'd it, but I was googling 'L't...not 'I't.

Thanks for the update though :)

Edit: Hrmm...just re-read it...it is 'L't, i.e. for less than. Interesting. I am having one of those days :(

Comment: You always welcome. There is jQuery API site, you can find there everything you need.

Comment: Hey Artem...I just tried this...and it doesn't work. I was looking at the syntax and I thought it would work - which is why I chose it as the answer.

I think the problem lies in the img:lt(5). I even tried img:eq(lt(5)) and that doesn't work. I don't think it saves the values in the variables correctly.

Comment: Please elaborate more, what do you want to achieve and what do you get instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the results in an array and then do a for loop, populating the array...I think you would need 2 arrays, one for origh and thumbh.

Comment: Have an example of actual code? I am not fully familiar with the syntax of jQuery - just learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? Or did you only want the first 4 img's?

```
$('#candidates img').fadeIn('normal').delay(300).animate({ height : $(this).height}, 1200, 'easeInQuad');
```

Comment: I want any number of images. I just used eq(0 - 3) as an example.

Assume I want the first 20 or 30 images. There should be no limit.

I would much rather change a for loop, and have it do it multiple times, than me having to re-write one line of code (manually) 20 times for 20 images.

Comment: But this doesn't do anything for the variables.